# Mongo Server Startup Warnings

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

```
$ ./bin/mongo 
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2014-08-09T15:26:23.251-0400 [initandlisten] 
2014-08-09T15:26:23.251-0400 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
```

Just want to fix the errors

Comment: This is a startup warning rather than an error. Unless you are going to be working with a large number of connections or data files, you can generally ignore this warning in your development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to fix this is setting the limit just before starting mongod with this:

```
ulimit -n 1024 && mongod
```

Or this:

```
launchctl limit maxfiles 1024 1024
```

Pls read full answer [here](http://tech.enekochan.com/en/2013/12/08/warning-soft-rlimits-too-low-in-mongodb-with-mac-os-x/).

Comment: An increase to 1024 is enough to make the startup warning go away, but potentially too low if you testing with larger connection or data load. The starting process limit on Linux machines is usually 1024 and [recommended ulimits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings) for production use are much higher.

Comment: it's good to keep it lower in development though, to catch potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem was addressed in MongoDb 3.0 manual.
Please check the below link

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/